# My magento 2 website is crashed: Unknown or bad timezone () error

Tags: magento2, error, timezone

[image]

When i am accessing my magento website i am getting errors

> DateTimeZone::__construct(): Unknown or bad timezone ()

on Block and CMS pages and all my product list pages on frontend shows 404 page not found error. Please check and help me out to fix this issue ASAP.
You can check this problem at here.
I solve this error by restoring my backup site.

But if you know why this error is coming then this question is still open

Comment: My answer hasn't helped you?

Comment: I'm currently having the same problem in Magento 2.1.3. The homepage works, but all other pages don't. My timezone is properly set in `core_config_data` to `Europe/Amsterdam`.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

I don't know exactly *HOW* it happened, but in my scenario the `core_config_data` table was corrupted. It had added a new row somehow with `path` set to `general` and `value` set to `NULL`:

[image: wrong configuration in database]

This caused `Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface::getValue()` on `public/vendor/magento/framework/Stdlib/DateTime/Timezone.php::scopeDate()` to return `NULL` instead of `Europe/Amsterdam`. Needless to say, when the `\DateTimeZone()` object was created it immediately threw this exception.

So if anyone else encounters this error, your configuration might be an obvious place to start looking.

Comment: I had the exact same problem. I mistakenly added a new line in the `core_cofig_data` table while trying to insert some entries for something different. I'm using SequelPro app on Mac and when I add a new row it automatically adds `general` under path

Comment: yup, same issue for me a quick easy way to get rid of it for future reference:`DELETE FROM core_config_data WHERE path LIKE 'general' AND value IS NULL LIMIT 1;`

Comment: Can confirm that this was the issue on M2 EE v 2.1.5. A clean install that was functioning until I installed uRapidFlow. Not sure if this is a Magento bug or if an issue with the extension.

Comment: u saved my day @giel

Comment: It worked as a charm, and don't forget to clean cache after deleting the "general" "NULL" line in the database ;)

Comment: oh man .. i love u .. u really saved my life @giel Berker

Comment: I can say this issue with blank/null values in core_config_data with path = 'general' has been an issue that even Magento 1 suffered from.

Comment: Wow, the same happened to me. How did this happen? I'm 100% sure I didn't make any manual database changes.

Comment: Same happend to us - we have no idea how. This answer was a lifesaver!

Answer (score 9):

The timezone should be one of the [List of Supported Timezones](http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.php). Seems that you are using empty timezone.

Try to detect the current store timezone using the next query:

```
SELECT * FROM `core_config_data` WHERE `path` = 'general/locale/timezone'
```

If result is empty, try to insert the default value:

```
INSERT INTO `core_config_data`(`path`, `value`) VALUES ('general/locale/timezone', 'Europe/Moscow')
```

If this does not help - try to search inside the project: where the code throws an error. Then try to debug it: detect from where the empty timezone value is coming.

Comment: I Have just revert back my old website by reverting backup .and we are working on deadline so I have not checked the issue which causing the issue But thank you for your answer. I have upvoted your answer and i will check If it is the same issue then I will Mark your answer as accepted

Comment: I faced this issue in a vanilla setup of 2.3.0 and solved it using above solution. Thanks @Siarhey

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem with the correct answer;

1,Select TO:

```
select * FROM `core_config_data` WHERE path = 'general'
```

2,Delete TO:

```
DELETE FROM `core_config_data` WHERE path = 'general'
```

Then the website is working, I hope to be useful to you.

Comment: Giel Berkers already answered the same what new you answered ??